# Check if time is in the range in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node js, getting time as input check if time is in the range of +3 hour and -3 hour on current time. Need simple check instead of using moment.js etc

```
   Input:
  let time= "22 Apr 2020 06:23:55";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// create Date Object from input string:
const inputTime = new Date("22 Apr 2020 06:23:55").getTime()

// get current time
const now = Date.now()

// calculate 3 hours time span 
const hhh = 60 * 60 * 3 * 1000

// calculate min && max
const min = now - hhh
const max = now + hhh

// check condition
return min < inputTime && inputTime < max
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use basic javascript Date object.

```
let dateToVerify = new Date("22 Apr 2020 06:23:55").getTime()
let now = new Date.getTime()
let range = (now - dateToVerify) / (1000 * 3600)
```

so if the date to verify is for exemple 22 Apr 2020 06:23:55 and the current time was 22 Apr 2020 08:23:55
the range would be 2 which is between your limit.

getTime() is in milliseconds.

The division by (1000 * 3600) is to give you the number of hours between your dates.

You could also divide by (1000 * 3600 * 24) to have a range in days.

Then

```
if (range <= 3 && range >= -3) {
  // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to create date object, then you can calculate like normal number in milliseconds

```
checkDate = ( dateStr , rangeH )=>{
    let timeRef = new Date(dateStr); // parse input string to date object
    let now = new Date(); // get current time
    let timeRange = rangeH * 60 * 60 * 1000; // calculate time range in milliseconds
    return now - timeRef < timeRange && timeRef - now < timeRange
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple JavaScript Math Object.

```
var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
var d2 = new Date("22 Apr 2020 06:23:55");  // some date
var timeDifference = (Math.abs(d1-d2))/1000;  // difference in Seconds
```

Or you can use like this

```
var timeDifference = (Math.abs(new Date()-new Date("22 Apr 2020 06:23:55")))/1000;  // difference in Seconds
```

You can compare this timeDifference with 10800 seconds.

You can convert this timeDifference to minutes by dividing it by 60.